# Need help setting a column value in the SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, case, inner-join

I am using the below code to update column value in the SQL JOIN statement.

```
   CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,1,1) = 1 then '1, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,2,1) = 1 then '2, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,3,1) = 1 then '3, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,4,1) = 1 then '4, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,5,1) = 1 then '5, ' else ''
   END                               AS    "x1",
```

For Example, if all the conditions are TRUE within the above CASE statements, the value for x1 will be "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, " but I need the value to be "1, 2, 3, 4, 5". How do I remove the last "Comma delimiter" from the string in the JOIN itself.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the comma at the end, put it at the start, and then remove the first character. Removing the first character is far easier in SQL Server, as you can use `STUFF` to remove it `STUFF(<String Expression>,1,1,'')`. As you have a comma (`,`) and a space (`' '`), then you need to remove 2 characters, not 1. YOu can also use `CONCAT` to remove the `ELSE ''`:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(CONCAT(CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,1,1) WHEN 1 then ', 1' END,
                    CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,2,1) WHEN 1 then ', 2' END,
                    CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,3,1) WHEN 1 then ', 3' END,
                    CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,4,1) WHEN 1 then ', 4' END,
                    CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,5,1) WHEN 1 then ', 5' END),1,2,'') AS x1
```

If you're on a more recent version of SQL you can use `CONCAT_WS` instead:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ,',CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,1,1) WHEN 1 then '1' END,
                      CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,2,1) WHEN 1 then '2' END,
                      CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,3,1) WHEN 1 then '3' END,
                      CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,4,1) WHEN 1 then '4' END,
                      CASE SUBSTRING(m.x1,5,1) WHEN 1 then '5' END) AS x1
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!
STUFF and CONCAT solution worked for me. I could not verify CONCAT_WS as my version does not support it.

Comment: If it answers the question, please do [mark it as the solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), @Tely .

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `concat_ws()`: it adds the separator in between its arguments, and, in SQL Server, has the nice feature of ignoring `null` values; this further simplify the code by avoiding the need of `else` branches to the `case` expressions.

```
concat_ws (',',
    case when substring(m.x1,1,1) = 1 then '1' end,
    case when substring(m.x1,2,1) = 1 then '2' end,
    case when substring(m.x1,3,1) = 1 then '3' end,
    case when substring(m.x1,4,1) = 1 then '4' end,
    case when substring(m.x1,5,1) = 1 then '5' end,
) as x1
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,1,1) = 1 then '1, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,2,1) = 1 then '2, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,3,1) = 1 then '3, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,4,1) = 1 then '4, ' else '' END
   + CASE when SUBSTRING(m.x1,5,1) = 1 then '5' else ''
   END                               AS    "x1
```

Comment: But any of the CASE out of 5 can be true. So I wan thinking if there is a way to remove the last character from that string within the query itself.